# Typescript getter returns undefined although the private property is set

Tags: typescript, inheritance, getter-setter

I've tried this code with TypeScript 2.6 and 3.4:

```
abstract class Base {
    private _prop = false;
    public get prop() { return this._prop; }
    public setProp(v) { this._prop = v; }

    private _otherProp = false;
    public get otherProp() { return this._otherProp; }
    public set otherProp(v) { this.setOtherProp(v); }    
    public setOtherProp(v) { this._otherProp = v; }
}

class MyBase extends Base {
    public set prop(v) { this.setProp(v); }
}

const base = new MyBase();

base.setProp(true);
base.setOtherProp(true);

console.log(`prop = ${base.prop}`); // prop = undefined
console.log(`otherProp = ${base.otherProp}`); // otherProp = true
```

Why the different result? Note that if I comment out the `set prop()` in the `MyBase` class then both properties return `true`, however this setter is never even executed, so why does it matter that it's there?

[Run the code yourself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=abstract%20class%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_prop%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20prop()%20%7B%20return%20this._prop%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_otherProp%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20otherProp()%20%7B%20return%20this._otherProp%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set%20otherProp(v)%20%7B%20this.setOtherProp(v)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20setProp(v)%20%7B%20this._prop%20%3D%20v%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20setOtherProp(v)%20%7B%20this._otherProp%20%3D%20v%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyBase%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20public%20set%20prop(v)%20%7B%20this.setProp(v)%3B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20base%20%3D%20new%20MyBase()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Abase.setProp(true)%3B%0D%0Abase.setOtherProp(true)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60prop%20%3D%20%24%7Bbase.prop%7D%60)%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60otherProp%20%3D%20%24%7Bbase.otherProp%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A) (results in the console)

Comment: Lol it looks like getter disappears if you add a setter. You probably can't override just one of those. After all, get/set are pointing to the same thing. Overriding one of them will override everything about that property.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override just the `set` of a property, you are overriding the whole property it's just that you leave `get` undefined. `get`/`set` syntax is just syntactic sugar for `Object.defineProperty` which overrides the whole property.

Override get, and call `super.prop` and it all works as expected:

```
abstract class Base {
    private _prop = false;
    public get prop() { return this._prop; }
    public setProp(v: boolean) { this._prop = v; }

    private _otherProp = false;
    public get otherProp() { return this._otherProp; }
    public set otherProp(v) { this.setOtherProp(v); }    
    public setOtherProp(v: boolean) { this._otherProp = v; }
}

class MyBase extends Base {

    public get prop() { return super.prop; }
    public set prop(v: boolean) { this.setProp(v); }
}

const base = new MyBase();

base.setProp(true);
base.setOtherProp(true);

console.log(`prop = ${base.prop}`); // prop = true
console.log(`otherProp = ${base.otherProp}`); // otherProp = true
```

[Playground link](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkIAOUAlgG7AR4D6FA9mQgLwIBmwyYOAbmKkyAVxDJKsBAHMciFmQAUASgIIo80VAB2CCAAtKYAHRMorAQgC+wkmIlSE-CAAULy6gC4EIZs2QcYB01fH0jU3NWDgRqK1s7cipaegQGZkMcKHdozh4+QUSHSWk5RAyDLJzlUI0tXXDjMwqqj3ii8RLneQQW7I8lalrDJpcAeUz+1kGVeNIEDsdpccnqwZ8-AKCQ9RHIvuqYuJtCBJQ0DABZAE9sfgQcAA96HQATDDu8InnFrrKk6a1TQQbR6MCiMhZEyKdrzYpOFwAzwbfyBYLDCImFxrIbtM7MHSQXy4GI6HAAdwQN0+qiEhBAuCx8jW0FEOFm9MZK0qU2UrPZdNgBLAWxMyGYMiUAANFDEACT4Bn8aEeaxS2YIAD0mqRMX5hCFhNF4slUoOHnlisZ5tYao12t6qwtnH1QA)

Comment: Your link works but in my project and at [typescriptlang.org](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), `super.prop` causes a compile error: "only public and protected methods of the base class are accessible via the 'super' keyword"