# Inherited setter erases inherited getter?

Tags: typescript

I noticed this sort of odd behavior using inheritance --.  If I define a getter in the parent, and I add a setter in the child, if I don't also specify the getter in the child, the getter returns undefined.  Is that by design?  What is the purpose?  If there is a rule that a getter and setter have to defined, seems like that should show up as a error at compile time instead of just return undefined even though the property is actually set by the setter.

```
class Parent {
    constructor(name_ : string) {
        this._name = name_
    }
    protected _name : string;
    get name() {return this._name}
}

class Dad extends Parent {
    set name(value: string) {
        this._name = value;
    }
    logName() {
        console.log(this._name);
    }
}

let steve = new Parent("Steve");
console.log(steve.name);  //Steve
let john = new Dad("John");
console.log(john.name);  //undefined
john.logName();          //John
```

Comment: This isn't specific to [tag:typescript], you can see the same behaviour from the emitted JS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript getter returns undefined although the private property is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56588363/typescript-getter-returns-undefined-although-the-private-property-is-set)